# How develop a Siri custom intent?

Tags: siri, sirikit, sirishortcuts

I'd like to develop a Siri custom intent that will allow the user to trigger a call via voice that causes an HTTPS end point to be called; the end point will return a textual response for Siri to speak. I've done some research and can see how to achieve this.

However, I cannot find any information on how to subsequently make the custom intent available to other Apple device users. Is there a publication mechanism similar to that for custom Alexa skills?

Thanks

Comment: You distribute custom intents as part your app. They're available to anybody who installs your app.

Comment: Intents ship with your App. Your app has to do the actual call, the intent could do preparation like select a receiver and starting it.